# Spring boot mocking static methods with PowerMock in Integration test

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm writing integration test on a RestController in SpringBoot.
Normally I would run with SpringRunner.class, but when it comes to Mock a static method I need to use PowerMock.

The strange fact is that when I run the single tests, they individually pass (but returns error messages), when I try to run the entire test class, no test passes and it returns the same error message.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({JwtUtils.class})
//@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class) THIS DOESN'T WORK!!!
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootJwtApplication.class)
public class RestAccessIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired @InjectMocks
  RestController restController;

  @Mock
  HttpServletRequest request;

  @Test
  public void operationsPerAccountWhenSuccessfulTest(){
    mockStatic(JwtUtils.class);
    when(JwtUtils.myMethod(request)).thenReturn("blabla");
    String expected = ... ;
    String actual = restController.getOperations();
    assertEquals(actual, expected);
  }

}
```

If I run the test or the entire class I get an error of this type:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.powermock.core.MockRepository.addAfterMethodRunner(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:50)

If I uncomment @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class) there it comes this other error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/core/testlisteners/GlobalNotificationBuildSupport$Callback
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.run(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:139)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to incompatibility in library version of PowerMock and Mockito. I suggest to check the compatibility version table provided by PowerMock team or to switch to JMockit to mock static and private methods.

Answer (score 2):

In the `when` method, try using `any(HttpServletRequest.class)` instead of the `request` mock object. Also use `MockHttpServletRequest` instead of mocking `HttpServletRequest`. This should work,

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(JwtUtils.class)
@PowerMockIgnore( {"javax.management.*"})
public class RestAccessIntegrationTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private RestController restController;

    private MockHttpServletRequest request;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(
                new ServletRequestAttributes(request));
    }

    @Test
    public void operationsPerAccountWhenSuccessfulTest() {
        mockStatic(JwtUtils.class);
        when(JwtUtils.myMethod(any(HttpServletRequest.class)))
           .thenReturn("blabla");

        String expected = ... ;
        // does your getOperations take HttpServletRequest
        // as parameter, then controller.getOperations(request);
        String actual = restController.getOperations();
        assertEquals(actual, expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you still using `@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootJwtApplication.class)`? I didn't get any exception when I don't use it.

Comment: I've tried with and without... I've used all the instructions you gave me. The weird thing is that each single test works, the whole class not.